# Track clicks on spreadsheet cells with an URL

Tags: google-sheets

I know I'm pushing the boundaries of what a Spreadsheet is but I want track the number of times a cell with an URL is clicked on.

URLs in cells are automatically turned into links by Google, this is quite convenient. I want a cell next to it which tells me how often that (generated) link was clicked.

```
+------+--------+
| Link | Clicks |
+------+--------+
| foo  |      0 |
| bar  |     33 |
| baz  |      1 |
+------+--------+
```

Is this a pipe dream or can it be done? I don't even know were to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time Google Sheets doesn't include built-in functions to do that. You require something else that track URL visits like [Google URL Shortener](http://goo.gl), [Google Analytics](http://analytics.google.com), among others. If the tool that you choose is able to publish to the web the number of clicks or has an API you could add that information to your spreadsheet through built-in functions like [IMPORTHTML()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en).

Google Analytics has a [URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=es) that could help you. Also there is an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) that help to pass data from Google Analytics to a Google spreadsheet.

---

**References**

- [Google spreadsheets function list - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)
- [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)